# Sharing local store between different KafkaStreams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Given: Have two KafkaStreams with DSL topology each one. Local state store is added to one of the typologies. What is the optimal way for the second KafkaStream to update the local store in the first KafkaStreams?

I could think about adding some processor to the KafkaStreams with local store. This processor has (1) some static task list populated by second KafkaStream,  (2) Punctuator which will process tasks from the task list.

Unfortunately, this design doesn't provide any guarantee for failure tolerate.

Any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Local state of an application should only be update by the application itself.

Not sure what you exactly want to achieve. One way to "update" state from a Kafka Streams instance might be via topic. Instance A creates a table from a topic. Instance B write into this topic when it want to update A's table-state.

Hope this helps. If not, maybe updated your question to give more details what you want to achieve.